# Dreamweaver mysql passing query to next page

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, recordset

I am working on a page using dreamweaver and mysql that lists work orders by  selected months
for example: view work orders  for october- user clicks link and the the work orders for the month of october are displayed.

my work orders page is one dynamic table off a recordset Details
called workorders.php

I created a query for october and it works however it is not passing on to the next page like it should it is listing all work orders and not the query `<a href="workorders.php?date=<?php echo $row_october['']; ?>">oct</a>`

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong in dreamweaver? thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste the code at here

Comment: could you post a bit more detail please?

Answer (score 0):

> Some suggestion:

1. Use selection or any other idea for selecting month & pass selected month as value to next page
   After that generate query for that month on next page and display result
2. Use Ajax. send selected month to process php, execute query and return to main  page
3. `<a href="workorders.php?date=<?php echo 'october'; ?>">oct</a>`

For more direction Paste Code